# Sorting data for plotting in mplot3d

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, matplotlib

I have been using mplot3d (part of matplotlib) for some various 3d plotting, and it has been performing the job admirably.  However, I have run into a new problem.

Mplot3d expects data to be sorted in a certain fashion, to plot a wireframe.  For example, it likes something like this:

```
x = array([[1, 2, 3],
          [1, 2, 3],
          [1, 2, 3]])

y = array([[1, 1, 1],
          [2, 2, 2],
          [3, 3, 3])
```

where z is then an array of the same dimensions, with data corresponding to each of those positions in space.

Unfortunately, my data isn't formatted like this - every other row is reversed, because the data is collected by scanning in a raster pattern.

So I have something more like:

```
x = array([[1, 2, 3],
          [3, 2, 1],
          [1, 2, 3]])
```

My current approach is a very ugly, brute-force "do a for loop then check if you're in an odd row or not" that builds a new array out of the old one, but I am hoping there is a more elegant way of doing this.  The tricky part is that I have to re-arrange the Z array in the same way I do the X and Y, to ensure that the data corresponding with each point is space is preserved.

Ideally, I'd like something that's robust and specifically designed to sort a set of 2-d arrays that contain arbitrary random position points, but even a more pythonic way of doing what I'm already doing would be appreciated.  If I could make it more robust, and not dependent on this specific raster scanning pattern, it would probably save me headaches in the long term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to do this: `x[1::2, :] = x[1::2, ::-1]`.

There are a few kinks... If you don't make an intermediate copy of `x` it doesn't quite do what you'd expect due to the way broadcasting works in numpy.

Nonetheless, it's still pretty simple to do with basic indexing:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[1,2,3]])
x_rev = x.copy()
x_rev[1::2, :] = x[1::2, ::-1]
```

This converts this (`x`):

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Into this (`x_rev`):

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

In case you're not familiar with slicing in python, `x[1::2]` would select every other item of `x`, starting with the second item.  (`1` is the the start index, `2` is the increment)  In contrast, `x[::-1]` just specifies an increment of `-1`, thus reversing the array. In this case we're only applying these slices to a particular axis, so we can select and reverse every other row, starting with the second row.

Comment: I had some experience with slicing, but hadn't thought of that exact approach, although now in retrospect it seems obvious - thanks!

I am still trying to think of a clever way to do a sorting that would work even if the arrangement of my data changes, but that's far less of a priority.

Comment: @user512679 - Well, if you just want to sort each row, you can just do `np.sort(x, axis=1)`